# Receiving [object object] from API

Tags: react-native

I tried for hours but could not extract the object value
when I execute api in postman tool I received successful message:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Raj",
        "City": "HYD",
        "Initial": "SSS"
    },
    {
        "Name": "JOHN",
        "City": "HYD",
        "Initial": "SSS"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Rakesh",
        "City": "HYD",
        "Initial": "SSS"
    }    
]
```

But when I am trying to access same from React native but it is showing me [object object]. How to extract Name field from it?

script:

```
  fetch('http://190.1.120.198:3538/CustomerList/api/userList', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {              
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username:'John',
    password:'UZ4952!',
    Organization:'NZE'          
  }),
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {        
    console.log("myMessage:"+responseJson);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Could you atleast show those vales in some Flatlist.  Just want to see value in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are trying to print the `responseJson` in logs by concatenating it with a string. When you add an object to string it will always print [object object].

```
console.log("myMessage:"+responseJson);
```

Output:

```
myMessage:[object object]
```

If you want to print the exact value of your json response you can do that in these two ways:

```
console.log("myMessage:",responseJson);
```

```
console.log("myMessage:"+JSON.stringify(responseJson));
```

Comment: My pleasure. I also struggled with this.